# React Native -> How do I fix the way my data is shown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm working on a react-native app. Basically I have a couple of components and there's that `component where I can enter certain data` say the name of an employee and `then I want that data, upon a button click, to be sent a different component, where the names would be shown`. So the way I actually send them through the screens is the following: I use **`materialBottoTabNavigation`** and upon clicking that button the data is saved in the `application's state`, after that it is `pushed into an array`(actually two arrays - one for the first name and a second one for the last name) which, after all that is done, are being sent to the list component using the n`avigation parameters`, and then finally I do a `flat list` over them but the problem is that they come up as: `"JohnDoeJohnDoeJohnDoe"`, while I want them to be like `Name - LastName` and then I want that to be repeated but ***keep the names one above each other***.
I believe the problem is that I am not really using the FlatList component correctly or the fact that I'm sending the arrays as properties to the component and hence the render in the format I've mentioned or both. I've tried sending the state directly but then I can't really say that the app functions the way I want it to, all the data within the list component is changed to the current state. I want it to be persisted. I've thought of using redux for that and I am looking for alternatives.
Here's the relevant code:

**Add names component:**

```
const firstNameContainer = []
const lastNameContainer = []
const saveNames =(firstNameToSave, lastNameToSave)=>{
  
    firstNameContainer.push(firstNameToSave)
    lastNameContainer.push(lastNameToSave)
  }
export default function addNames({navigation}) {
    const[firstName, setFistName] = useState();
    const[lastName, setLastName] = useState();
  
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>add names screen</Text>
  
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder='Enter first name'
            multiline={false}
            keyboardType='default'
            onChangeText={firstName=>setNames(firstName)}>
          </TextInput>
  
           <TextInput
            style={styles.inputTranslation}
            placeholder='Enter last name'
            multiline={false}
            keyboardType='default'
            onChangeText={lastName=>setLastName(lastName)}>
          </TextInput> 
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={()=>saveNames(firstName, lastName)}> 
            <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Add Names</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Button
                title='Save Names'
                onPress={()=>{
                    navigation.navigate('NamesList', {firstName: firstNameContainer, lastName: lastNameContainer, key: 1})
                }}></Button>
```

And this is my `list component`:

```
export default function NamesList({route, navigation}){
    const {firstName, lastName} =route.params;
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList
     
        data={firstName}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{firstName}</Text>
                <Text>{lastName}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>)}
        />

      </View>
      
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood correctly, do you want to have a list of employees displayed? (with their first name and last name)

Comment: Yes and I want the names to be on the same row, with a couple of pixels apart, then I want the second person's name to be on the next row with a couple of pixels apart between the first name and the last name and it goes on and on in the same way ad infinitum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save name as an object in the array

```
const names = []

const saveNames =(firstNameToSave, lastNameToSave)=>{
     names.push({firstName:firstNameToSave,
                 lastName:lastNameToSave}) 
  }
```

and pass

```
 <Button
                title='Save Names'
                onPress={()=>{
                    navigation.navigate('NamesList', {namesList: names, key:1})
                }}></Button>
```

and show like this

```
export default function NamesList({route, navigation}){
    const {namesList} =route.params;
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList
     
        data={namesList}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.firstName} - {item.lastName}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>)}
        />

      </View>
      
    )
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

i didnt quite understand what u wanted.. do u want the name to be displayed like
John - Doe
John - Doe
John - Doe
?? or just one John - Doe

i havent tested this out but it shoudl work i think.

this is the addnames page

```js
export default const addName=({navigation})=>{
  const [firstName,setFirstName] = useState()
  const [lastName,setLastName] = useState()
  var names = []
  const pushName = (firstName,lastName)=>{
    names.push([firstName,lastName])
  }

  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput
      placeHolder='first Name'
      onChangeText={(firstNameEntered)=>setFirstName(firstNameEntered)}/>
      <TextInput
      placeHolder='last Name'
      onChangeText={(lastNameEntered)=>setLastName(lastNameEntered)}/>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
        pushName(firstName, lastName)
        navigation.navigate('names',{names:names, key:1})
      }}> 
        <Text>Add Names</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

now the names page

```js
export default function NamesList({route, navigation}){
    const {names} =route.params;
    return(
      <View>
        <ScrollView>
        {names &&
        names.map((name)=>{
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{name[0]} - {name[1]}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
}
```

sry if i made some mistakes i havent ran these and im quite new to react and react native